# Creating a "QA Testing" state in Jira

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I am very new to JIRA and I have been asked to create QA Testing state.  I have developed two projects and JIRA is linked to Confluence.  I'm a little stumped as to how to create this QA Testing state.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut to add/view Statuses is gg + Status. From that page you can add a new Status to use anywhere in JIRA.

However, if you have JIRA version 7 and above (or Cloud JIRA), you can add a status directly from a workflow where it will be used:

1. Type 'gg'
2. Type 'Workflows'
3. Edit the workflow where you want to see the new status
4. Click 'Diagram' towards the top (not text)
5. Click 'Add Status'towards the top

You'll have to drag and drop transitions (lines) to incorporate the new status in your workflow. Then make sure to publish the workflow so it can be used!

Comment: If the workflow is used by multiple projects, it can be a good idea to create a copy, edit the copy, and set that as the workflow for the project. I find Jira admin operations prone to unintended side effects. Also, love the username.